# Apache configuration with proxy and location

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, http-proxy

I want to map these domains to these ports. How can I do it?

```
http://test1.example.com/phpmyadmin/    example.com:80/phpmyadmin/
http://test1.example.com/app1/          example.com:8080/app1/
http://test1.example.com/app2/          example.com:8090/app2/

http://webmin.example.com/              example.com:10000/
```

This is what i did. Problem is phpmyadmin is not working it is forwarded to glassfish.

webmin is working because it is a seperate domain.

How can I map phpmyadmin to thesame domain? http://test1.example.com/phpmyadmin/

Thanks

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName              test1.example.com
    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass           /           http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /           http://localhost:8080/

    ProxyPass           /admin/     https://localhost:4848/
    ProxyPassReverse    /admin/     https://localhost:4848/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      test1.example.com/phpmyadmin/
    DocumentRoot    /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    Alias           /phpmyadmin     /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    Alias           /mysql          /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName              webmin.example.com
    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass           /               http://localhost:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse    /               http://localhost:10000/
</VirtualHost>
```